# Different Text Sizes for different Screen Sizes, using what ratio factor?

Tags: android

Hello I am using different textsizes depending on different screen sizes.
Like:

```
values-small: dimens.xml -> ?
values-normal: dimens.xml -> 10sp
values-large: dimens.xml -> ?
values-xlarge: dimens.xml -> ?
```

I want to know if there is a formula to set the right sizes depending on small, large, xlarge instead of setting sp size by testing it on different screens^^?

second question: is values-normal neccessary, isnt "values" folder == values-normal?

third question: what happens when I declare dimens.xml for small, normal, and large and the device is a XLARGE device will it use dimens.xml from values? or valuse-normal? or the next smaller one values-large?

thank you

Comment: Same ratio as ldpi:mdpi:hdpi:xhdpi => 0.75:1:1.5:2

Comment: `is values-normal neccessary,` NO. `isnt "values" folder == values-normal` almost. It's **like** `drawable` and `drawable-mdpi` for drawables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to know if there is a formula to set the right sizes depending on small, large, xlarge instead of setting sp size by testing it on different screens

Not really. Many apps do not change their font size at all based on screen size, just as most Web apps do not change their font size based on browser window size. Of course, you are certainly welcome to specify different `<dimen>` resources for different screen sizes, including dimensions for use with text. And there's nothing stopping you from using an algorithm like the others suggest; just understand that there's no real reason to use that algorithm. To put it another way, a graphic designer should be telling you how big to make the text, not a calculator.

Moreover, the `-small`, `-normal`, etc. buckets are not used as much anymore, in favor of the more flexible `-wNNNdp`, `-hNNNdp`, and `-swNNNdp` buckets.

> isnt "values" folder == values-normal?

No.

Suppose you have `res/values-small/`, `res/values/`, `res/values-large/`, and `res/values-xlarge/`. Further suppose that each resource set defines a `text_size` dimension resource, and you use that in in layouts (e.g., `@dimen/text_size`).
A `-normal` device will then pull from `res/values-small/`, as `-small` is for `small` screens *or larger*. Your `res/values/` version of the resource will never be used. Hence, the typical pattern would be not have `res/values-small/`, putting your `-small` resources in `res/values/`, and overriding that default value in `res/values-normal/`, `res/values-large/`, and `res/values-xlarge/`.

> what happens when I declare dimens.xml for small, normal, and large and the device is a XLARGE device will it use dimens.xml from values? or valuse-normal? or the next smaller one values-large?

It should pull from `res/values-large/`, as that is the closest match among the qualifying resource sets.

Comment: Hmm... well so, when I have values-small folder,... normal, large, xlarge - the default values folder will never be called?

Comment: @Steven: Correct. Every screen size matches one of your more specific resource sets. This is a problem for things like string resources that are not (usually) dependent upon screen size. **Always** have a default directory (e.g., `res/values/`). The key is what goes in that directory. In the case where you want dimensions to vary by screen size (e.g., padding or margins), put the smallest size in the default directory, and override the values for larger sizes in size-specific directories.

Comment: `put the smallest size in the default directory` hmmm... not the **mdpi** (normal, not smallest) equivalent?

Comment: @DerGolem: Screen size is not screen density. They are independent variables, and the resource system handles them independently. For historical/backwards-compatibility reasons, for *drawables*, `-mdpi` is synonymous with the default directory (e.g., `res/drawable/` is assumed to hold `-mdpi` resources, for any bitmaps in that directory).

Comment: I assume the same goes for `res/values` is assumed to hold the **normal** values, not the smallest?

Comment: @DerGolem: You don't put drawables in `res/values/`, and having density-dependent resource sets for anything *other* than drawables (e.g., `res/values-hdpi/`) is a serious code smell IMHO.

Comment: I'm talking about **dimens.xml**, not *drawables*. Since the OP asked for `Different Text Sizes`, not images.

Comment: @DerGolem: But the OP did *not* ask about different text sizes based upon density. If you have concerns related to that, ask a separate Stack Overflow question, please.

Comment: No, I have no concerns about that. I **know exactly** how to manage drawables and dimensions and where to put the ones and the others.

Comment: okay thank you - so it's better to have values (content same as values-normal), values-small, values-normal, values-large, values-xlarge

Comment: @Steven: "so it's better to have values (content same as values-normal)" -- no. Quoting myself from an earlier comment, "in the case where you want dimensions to vary by screen size (e.g., padding or margins), put the smallest size in the default directory, and override the values for larger sizes in size-specific directories".

Answer (score 2):

This is the common problem in majority of Android projects to support varied screen sizes.

In short, you can make use of [scalable DP](https://github.com/intuit/sdp) and [scalable Font](https://github.com/intuit/ssp) approach.

Android project structure inherently allows specifying different font size (SP) and margin values (DP) by defining them in dimens.xml files for supported screen sizes. But the problem that still remain is - what values to be used ? UX designers normally provide style guides for only one set (e.g. 360x640 DP screen size) and don't provide for all other supported screen sizes. So the problem to use right vlaues for other supported screen sizes still remain unanswered.

One good solution (per my understading) is to use readymade scalable dictionary of dimens.xml files, something similar to the dictionary of files provided by [this](https://github.com/intuit/ssp/tree/master/ssp-android/src/main/res) library. After adding these xml files to project, you just need to use the keys in your layouts, then Android automatically uses font/margin value from respective directory. Please refer [here](https://github.com/intuit/sdp) for visual difference - with and without this approach.

Comment: Is it that nobody tried out the libraries suggested on this link. The second one seems pretty good and convenient to me. I am yet to try out the first one, though

Comment: @gbenroscience, I've used both libraires (in fact extracting the mappings files for SSP and SDP for supported screens) and the results are quite satisfactory and its in production for quite sometime now !

Comment: I wonder what the response would be like if this libraries were from someone like Google. Anyway no worries, I aim to use them from now on and spread word about it. Great job @birender!

Answer (score 1):

I use the ratio **0.75 : 1 : 1.5 : 2** same as for DPIs. It works fine.